# dbt run_query() with a where clause based on argument

Tags: google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt, dbt-bigquery

I am trying to set query and call `run_query()` in a dbt macro called `get_records` but unable to set the query correctly using the argument in the where clause. Here is the macro:

```
{% macro get_records(lead_id) %}
    {% set sql_statement %}
        select lead_record from {{ ref('source_table') }} where lead_id = {{ lead_id }} limit 1
    {% endset %}
    {{ print(query) }}
    {% if execute %}
        {% set results = run_query(sql_statement) %}
        {% set records = results.columns[0].values() %}
    {% else %}
        {% set records = [] %}
    {% endif %}
    -- do something here
{% endmacro %}
```

But, the query `select lead_record from {{ ref('source_table') }} where lead_id = {{ lead_id }} limit 1` getting compiled as following:

```
select lead_record from `source` where lead_id = lead_id
```

which is wrong. Is there a way to set a query using the argument value in where clause ? thanks!.

Comment: {{ lead_id }} returns a string without quotation, need to add it like lead_id = '{{ lead_id }}'